# React conditional sorting of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a value from redux state and I wish to sort an array based conditionally on what I get from the state.

The current way I've written this is as follows:

```js
class ProductsPage extends Component {

    state = {
        productArrayFromBackend: [],
        productArrayToDisplay: []
    }

    render() {
        let ProductArrayToProcess = []

        if (this.props.ProductFilter == "latest") {
            ProductArrayToProcess = this.state.productArrayToDisplay.sort((a, b) => (a.addedOn > b.addedOn ? -1 : 1))
        } else if (this.props.ProductFilter == "popular") {
            ProductArrayToProcess = this.state.productArrayToDisplay.sort((a, b) => (a.likes > b.likes ? -1 : 1))
        }
        else {
            ProductArrayToProcess = this.state.productArrayToDisplay
        }

        return (
            <figure>
                <div className="product-warp">
                    {ProductArrayToProcess.map((product, i) => <ProductThumbnailElement key={i} Product={product} />)}
                </div>
            </figure>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, the value for `this.props.ProductFilter` is coming from state. What I wish to do is when the value in the redux state changes, it should change the value that is rendered inside the `jsx` too.

Please let me know how is that possible?

Comment: how to achieve this then? Please let me know. I am getting confused and not able to sort this.

Comment: It's unclear what's not working and what you're trying to do.

Comment: conditionally sort an array

Comment: From a general review - this code suppose to work, what can you tell us about the effect on the DOM?

Comment: Array sort mutates the state which is an anti-pattern in react.

Comment: we need to know where your data comes from.you are doing `this.state.productArrayToDisplay` but since your state is initialised with [], you will have no data in this component. the state you have in your component is different than the state of your store. Here you just have no data, or maybe you didn't provide enough of your code for us to help. Maybe `this.state.productArrayToDisplay` is in fact a props mapped with mapStateToProps ?

Answer (score -1):

You could simply extract the your required data inside the `render` function.

```
render(){
const {ProductFilter} = this.props;
// use ProductFilter in the following code using JSX
}
```

Simply declaring the variable once at the begging is a better practice than calling `this.props.X` several time.

Furthermore, instead of calling the change items from the `state` directly, you might want to copy their value, and make changes upon this copy.

BTW, I'll suggest to export the `ProductArrayToProcess` generation to a matching function, there of course you'll still have the access of `props` and `state`.